# Счетчик ответов в приложении

Tags: android

Пытаюсь написать небольшую игру типа викторины. В общем-то все получилось, только застрял в одном месте. Есть два счетчика правильных (correctCount) и неправильных (incorrectCount) ответов. Дело в том, что когда отвечаю на последний вопрос викторины как бы я не ответил правильно или неправильно в счетчики не записывается, что я ответил правильно или неправильно. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильнее реализовать счетчик?

Например в викторине есть 4 вопроса, на первые три отвечаю неправильно, а на последний правильно, но в переменной correctCount оказывается в итоге 0.

Вот что у меня сейчас есть

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ***

    private int correctCount = 0; //Количество правильных ответов
    private int incorrectCount = 0; //Количество неправильных ответов

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        currentQuestion = questionsList.get(qid);

        updateQuestionAndOptions();
    }

    //Метод обновляет вопрос и варианты ответа. Если правильно ответили на предыдущий
    private void updateQuestionAndOptions() {
        //Выводим вопрос
        questionText.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
        //Выводим варианты ответов
        btnA.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt1());
        btnB.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt2());
        btnC.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt3());
        btnD.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt4());

        //Устанавливаем количество монет
        coinText.setText(String.valueOf(coinValue));

        //Увеличиваем число монет на 5 т.к. мы перешли к следующему вопросу, а значит на предыдущий правильно ответили
        coinValue = coinValue + 5;

        questionNumber.setText("№ " + String.valueOf(questionValue));

        //Увеличиваем номер вопроса на 1
        questionValue++;

        //Выводим количество жизней
        lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
    }

    //Метод обновляет вопрос и варианты ответа. Если НЕ правильно ответили на предыдущий
    private void updateQuestionAndOptionsIncorrect() {
        //Выводим вопрос
        questionText.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
        //Выводим варианты ответов
        btnA.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt1());
        btnB.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt2());
        btnC.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt3());
        btnD.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt4());

        //Устанавливаем количество монет
        //coinText.setText(String.valueOf(coinValue));

        questionNumber.setText("№ " + String.valueOf(questionValue));

        //Увеличиваем номер вопроса на 1
        questionValue++;

        //Выводим количество жизней
        lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
    }

    //Когда игра закончилась
    private void gameOver() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("correct", correctCount);
        intent.putExtra("incorrect", incorrectCount);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }

    //Нажатие на первый вариант ответа
    public void onBtnA(View view) {

        if (currentQuestion.getOpt1().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
            btnA.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightGreen));

            if (qid < questionsList.size() - 1) {
                //Правильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                correctAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
        } else {
            //Если ответили неправильно
            lifeValue--;
            lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
            btnA.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightRed));

            if (qid < questionsList.size() - 1) {
                //Неправильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                incorrectAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }

            //Если жизней не осталось, то выходим из викторины
            if (lifeValue == 0) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onBtnB(View view) {

        if (currentQuestion.getOpt2().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
            btnB.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightGreen));


            if (qid < questionsList.size() - 1) {
                //Правильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                correctAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
        } else {
            //Если ответили неправильно
            lifeValue--;
            lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
            btnB.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightRed));


            if (qid < questionsList.size() - 1) {
                //Неправильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                incorrectAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }

            //Если жизней не осталось, то выходим из викторины
            if (lifeValue == 0) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onBtnC(View view) {

        if (currentQuestion.getOpt3().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
            btnC.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightGreen));


            if (qid < questionsList.size() - 1) {
                //Правильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                correctAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
        } else {
            //Если ответили неправильно
            lifeValue--;
            lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
            btnC.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightRed));


            if (qid < questionsList.size() - 1) {
                //Неправильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                incorrectAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }

            //Если жизней не осталось, то выходим из викторины
            if (lifeValue == 0) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onBtnD(View view) {

        if (currentQuestion.getOpt4().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
            btnD.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightGreen));


            if (qid < questionsList.size() - 1) {
                //Правильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                correctAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
        } else {
            //Если ответили неправильно
            lifeValue--;
            lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
            btnD.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightRed));


            if (qid < questionsList.size() - 1) {
                //Неправильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                incorrectAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }

            //Если жизней не осталось, то выходим из викторины
            if (lifeValue == 0) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    //Если пользователь ответил правильно
    private void correctAnswer() {

        //Делаем задержку на 1 сек. перед обновлением следующего вопроса
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Увеличиваем на единицу счетчик вопросов
                qid++;

                //Увеличиваем количество правильных ответов
                correctCount++;

                currentQuestion = questionsList.get(qid);

                //Обновляем текст вопроса, варианты ответа и т.д.
                updateQuestionAndOptions();

                //Сброс цветов
                resetColor();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    //Если пользователь ответил НЕ правильно
    private void incorrectAnswer() {

        //Делаем задержку на 1 сек. перед обновлением следующего вопроса
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Увеличиваем на единицу счетчик вопросов
                qid++;

                //Увеличиваем количество неправильных ответов
                incorrectCount++;

                currentQuestion = questionsList.get(qid);

                //Обновляем текст вопроса, варианты ответа и т.д.
                updateQuestionAndOptionsIncorrect();

                //Сброс цветов
                resetColor();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: В чем проблема в моем вопросе?

Comment: Много кода не относящегося к вопросу

Comment: ок.. сейчас сокращу. Убрал лишние методы и переменные

Comment: зачем используется postDelay? куча кода, который можно было сократить раза так в 2-3! И читалось бы лучше. Я так понимаю что срабатывает gameOver() и количество ответов остается не просчитанным.

Comment: postDelay использую чтобы была задержка и игрок увидел правильный ответ, который зеленым светится. Как сделать, чтобы считалось?

Comment: @Kolhoznik на примере onBtnA() - если пользователь не правильно ответил  уменьшаешь же переменную lifeValue сразу, а эти переменные почему то в Handler попадают сначала.

Comment: т.е. лучше прям в условии если неправильно ответил увеличить число неправильных ответов на 1?

Comment: @Kolhoznik да, можешь увеличивать переменную до вызова handler. И еще подумай над упрощением кода. Чтобы не использовать кучу одинакового кода для каждой кнопки, можно сделать только один метод, и внутри него с помощью case проверять ID кнопки и выполнять нужные операции. Так можно сократить количество ошибок до минимума.

Comment: Я так делал. Т.е. например для кнопки btnA перед вызовом incorrectAnswer(); писал incorrectCount++;, а в самом методе incorrectAnswer() убирал код, который увеличивает переменную incorrectCount. Не помогло. А на счет switch case я так и думал сделать, но пока хотелось бы реализовать рабочий код.

Comment: @Kolhoznik в условии qid < questionsList.size() - 1 - на последнем вопросе всегда будет срабатывать false, а там только метод gameOver();

Comment: Вот и у меня мысли по поводу этого условия для последнего вопроса. На последнем вопросе всегда False. Что можно придумать тут?

Comment: Рекомендую почитать книги: П.Дейтел "Android для разработчиков", 3-е издание 2016 г. и Б.Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов", 3-e издание - 2016 г. В обоих этих книгах очень подробно разбирается создание игры-викторины. С их помощью вы научитесь правильно проектировать приложение (в вашем коде много проблем) и многим другим вещам, необходимым android-разработчику, а если прочитаете их полностью, то сможете сами отвечать тут на вопросы, а не ждать помощи других :)

Comment: Уже разобрался. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Разобрались - это хорошо. Не хотите ответом оформить?

Comment: Позже оформлю.. уже отошел. Может заодно гуру подскажут более лучшее решение тоже. )

Answer (score 1):

Вот что в итоге у меня получилось. Как в комментариях писали пока не стал использовать switch case, но зато вроде работает. Наверняка есть более лучшее решение, если кто-то предложит лучшее решение был бы рад.

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DBHelper db;
    private QuestionModel currentQuestion; //Текущий вопрос
    private List<QuestionModel> questionsList; //Список вопросов
    private int qid = 0; //Своего рода индекс текущего вопроса (номер вопроса)
    private int timeValue = 30; //Начальное значение таймера
    private int coinValue = 0; //Начальное значение монет
    private int questionValue = 1;
    private int lifeValue = 5; //Количество жизней
    private int correctCount = 0; //Количество правильных ответов
    private int incorrectCount = 0; //Количество неправильных ответов

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; //Таймер

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //Заполняем коллекцию вопросами
        questionsList = db.getAllQuestions();

        //Случайным образом перемешиваем вопросы
        Collections.shuffle(questionsList);

        currentQuestion = questionsList.get(qid);

        //Устанавливаем количество монет
        coinText.setText(String.valueOf(coinValue));

        //Таймер
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                //Пишем логику для timerText
                timerText.setText(String.valueOf(timeValue) + "\"");

                //С каждой итерацией уменьшаем время (timeValue) на 1
                timeValue -= 1;

                //Если время вышло
                if (timeValue == -1) {
                    //Завершаем викторину
                    timeUp();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //Завершаем викторину
                timeUp();
            }
        }.start();

        //Обновляем вопрос и варианты ответа. Если правильно ответили на предыдущий
        updateQuestionAndOptions();
        //initFirstQuestion();
    }

    //Метод обновляет вопрос и варианты ответа. Если правильно ответили на предыдущий
    private void updateQuestionAndOptions() {
        //Выводим вопрос
        questionText.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
        //Выводим варианты ответов
        btnA.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt1());
        btnB.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt2());
        btnC.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt3());
        btnD.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt4());

        //Устанавливаем значение таймера вновь равным 30
        timeValue = 30;

        //Отменяем таймер и вновь запускаем для нового вопроса
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer.start();

        questionNumber.setText("№ " + String.valueOf(questionValue));

        //Увеличиваем номер вопроса на 1
        questionValue++;

        //Выводим количество жизней
        lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
    }

    //Метод обновляет вопрос и варианты ответа. Если НЕ правильно ответили на предыдущий
    private void updateQuestionAndOptionsIncorrect() {
        //Выводим вопрос
        questionText.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
        //Выводим варианты ответов
        btnA.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt1());
        btnB.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt2());
        btnC.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt3());
        btnD.setText(currentQuestion.getOpt4());

        //Устанавливаем значение таймера вновь равным 30
        timeValue = 30;

        //Отменяем таймер и вновь запускаем для нового вопроса
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer.start();

        //Устанавливаем количество монет
        //coinText.setText(String.valueOf(coinValue));

        questionNumber.setText("№ " + String.valueOf(questionValue));

        //Увеличиваем номер вопроса на 1
        questionValue++;

        //Выводим количество жизней
        lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
    }

    //Метод для запуска активности, когда время вышло
    private void timeUp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }

    //Когда игра закончилась
    private void gameOver() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("correct", correctCount);
        intent.putExtra("incorrect", incorrectCount);
        intent.putExtra("coins", coinValue);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }

    //Если пользователь свернул игру и вновь открыл, то таймер продолжится
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    //Когда активити останавливается, таймер будет останавливаться
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    //Остановка таймера
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    //Нажатие на первый вариант ответа
    public void onBtnA(View view) {
        //Сравнивает выбранный ответ с правильным ответом и если правильно, делает кнопку зеленым
        if (currentQuestion.getOpt1().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
            btnA.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightGreen));

            //Проверяем не превышаем ли границы очереди вопросов. Т.е. был ли это последний вопрос или можно перейти к следующему.
            if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                //Правильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                correctAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
        } else {
            //Если ответили неправильно
            lifeValue--;
            lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
            btnA.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightRed));

            //Проверяем не превышаем ли границы очереди вопросов. Т.е. был ли это последний вопрос или можно перейти к следующему.
            if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                //Неправильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                incorrectAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }

            //Если жизней не осталось, то выходим из викторины
            if (lifeValue == 0) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onBtnB(View view) {
        //Сравнивает выбранный ответ с правильным ответом и если правильно, делает кнопку зеленым
        if (currentQuestion.getOpt2().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
            btnB.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightGreen));

            //Проверяем не превышаем ли границы очереди вопросов. Т.е. был ли это последний вопрос или можно перейти к следующему.
            if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                //Правильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                correctAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
        } else {
            //Если ответили неправильно
            lifeValue--;
            lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
            btnB.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightRed));

            //Проверяем не превышаем ли границы очереди вопросов. Т.е. был ли это последний вопрос или можно перейти к следующему.
            if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                //Неправильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                incorrectAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }

            //Если жизней не осталось, то выходим из викторины
            if (lifeValue == 0) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onBtnC(View view) {
        //Сравнивает выбранный ответ с правильным ответом и если правильно, делает кнопку зеленым
        if (currentQuestion.getOpt3().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
            btnC.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightGreen));

            //Проверяем не превышаем ли границы очереди вопросов. Т.е. был ли это последний вопрос или можно перейти к следующему.
            if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                //Правильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                correctAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
        } else {
            //Если ответили неправильно
            lifeValue--;
            lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
            btnC.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightRed));

            //Проверяем не превышаем ли границы очереди вопросов. Т.е. был ли это последний вопрос или можно перейти к следующему.
            if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                //Неправильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                incorrectAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }

            //Если жизней не осталось, то выходим из викторины
            if (lifeValue == 0) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onBtnD(View view) {
        //Сравнивает выбранный ответ с правильным ответом и если правильно, делает кнопку зеленым
        if (currentQuestion.getOpt4().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
            btnD.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightGreen));

            //Проверяем не превышаем ли границы очереди вопросов. Т.е. был ли это последний вопрос или можно перейти к следующему.
            if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                //Правильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                correctAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
        } else {
            //Если ответили неправильно
            lifeValue--;
            lifeText.setText(String.valueOf(lifeValue));
            btnD.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorLightRed));

            //Проверяем не превышаем ли границы очереди вопросов. Т.е. был ли это последний вопрос или можно перейти к следующему.
            if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                //Неправильно ответили и переходим к следующему вопросу
                incorrectAnswer();
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }

            //Если жизней не осталось, то выходим из викторины
            if (lifeValue == 0) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    //Если пользователь ответил правильно
    private void correctAnswer() {

        //Делаем задержку на 1 сек. перед обновлением следующего вопроса
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Останавливаем таймер
                //countDownTimer.cancel();

                //Увеличиваем число монет на 5 т.к. мы перешли к следующему вопросу, а значит на предыдущий правильно ответили
                coinValue = coinValue + 5;

                //Устанавливаем количество монет
                coinText.setText(String.valueOf(coinValue));

                //Увеличиваем количество правильных ответов
                correctCount++;

                //Увеличиваем на единицу счетчик вопросов
                qid++;

                if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                    //Теперь текущим вопросов становится следующий т.к. мы увеличили qid на 1
                    currentQuestion = questionsList.get(qid);
                } else {
                    gameOver();
                }

                //Обновляем текст вопроса, варианты ответа и т.д.
                updateQuestionAndOptions();

                //Сброс цветов
                resetColor();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    //Если пользователь ответил НЕ правильно
    private void incorrectAnswer() {

        //Делаем задержку на 1 сек. перед обновлением следующего вопроса
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Останавливаем таймер
                //countDownTimer.cancel();

                //Увеличиваем количество неправильных ответов
                incorrectCount++;

                //Увеличиваем на единицу счетчик вопросов
                qid++;

                if (qid < questionsList.size()) {
                    //Теперь текущим вопросов становится следующий т.к. мы увеличили qid на 1
                    currentQuestion = questionsList.get(qid);
                } else {
                    gameOver();
                }

                //Обновляем текст вопроса, варианты ответа и т.д.
                updateQuestionAndOptionsIncorrect();

                //Сброс цветов
                resetColor();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```